# a little problem with C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want to implement a function which has a variable number of arguments. This function allows me to call another function using the list of optional arguments. The purpose of this function is to call any function depending on some conditions (depending on the called functions, if the two first arguments are equal, we call the function). My problem is, the functions that can be called don't have the same number of arguments and thus, I don't know how to pass the arguments everytime I have a different function

For example, if I have this:

```
void func(int value_to_compare, int compared_value, int arg_number, char *arg_types, char *function_name, ...)
```

I can call it like:

```
char arg1;
int arg2, arg3;
int condition1;

func(condition1, 1, 1, "c", func1, arg1);
func(condition1, 0, 2, "ci", func2, arg1, arg2);
func(arg2, 0 , 3, "cii", func3, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

and the functions called are like:

```
func1(char);
func2(char, int);
func3(char, int, int);
```

I try to explain more, if I have for example:

```
struct element_list {
char *element_type;
char *element_name;
}
```

the structures in my case have a big number of elements, the condition must be passed as an argument to the function, and the condition value depends on a context, so I have to be able to call 'func' in any context, I just give the condition and the value, and then a function will be called with the corresponding arguments, so it will be something like

```
func(element_list.element_type, "CHAR", func1, "s", element_list.element_name);
```

in addition to that, I have a huge number of functions, and a huge number of conditions, so I need something that is as generic as possible.

Comment: How flexible do you need to be? Depending on your architecture you might be able to get away with typedeffing a lot of function types that accept 0-15 register-size arguments, say ints, and then cast whatever you have into ints to pass (breaking larger values into two, etc.) Or if you know in advance that there's only a small set of argument combinations you could implement this with specific typedeffed function pointers. Or you could go the whole hog and code the function call and calling convention in assembler yourself.

Comment: There is a big number of functions, each with a different set of arguments

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What is the relationship of func to func1, func2 etc?

Comment: @Neil: `func` is some kind of wrapper/front-end that checks some conditions and decides whether to actually call `func1`, `func2` etc.. :-/

Comment: @Mansuro: "...depending on some conditions" - can you illustrate some of the conditions... could help us give an answer that preserves the ability to check them....

Comment: @Tony I did some editing to explain it more

Comment: I can't see what you're trying to achieve yet... sorry.  How does your `func` idea improve or functionally differ from `if (condition1 == 1) func1(arg1); if (condition1 == 0) func2(arg1, arg2);`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's how I did

```
void func(int value_type, void *value_to_compare, void *compared_value, char *arg_types, void (*function_name)(), ...)
```

I make a switch on value_type, depending on the type, I make a cast on value_to_compare, and compared_value, I store these values in two different unions, and then I compare them and in the case the values are equal, I call the function function_name. Concerning the function to call, I make casts depending on the arg_types, and then I do something very stupid, which is a switch like:

```
switch(strlen(arg_types)) {
case 0:
function_name();
break;
case 1:
function_name(args[0]);
break;
case 2:
function_name(args[0], args[1]);
break;
...
}
```

where args is

```
void* args[MAX_NUMBER_ARGS];
```

I take every element of the array args and depending on arg_types, I make a cast, but I couldn't find a better solution...

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you're doing, right now **you are working around the type system.** There's no typesafe way of doing what you want in C.

Having that in mind:

One possible solution is to make all that functions of the same type: `typedef void my_func_type(void*)` and let each function "decrypt" the parameter on its own.

Another solution is to **rethink your design** - and this is the solution I sincerely recommend to you. But first you'd need to say a bit more on what you want to achieve here... A good starting point would be to show how exactly you intend to use such functionality. Chances are that you'll end up not needing this at all...

---

**Continued, #1**

From what I've understood, you'd want to write such `func` that this code

```
char arg1;
int arg2, arg3;
int condition1;

func(condition1, 1, 1, "c", func1, arg1);
func(condition1, 0, 2, "ci", func2, arg1, arg2);
func(arg2, 0 , 3, "cii", func3, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

would behave like:

```
if (condition1 == 1) func1(arg1);
if (condition1 == 0) func2(arg1, arg2);
if (arg2 == 0)       func3(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Frankly... The best way is to write it just like this. :-)

Since you're asking this question, chances are you want something more complicated that. The situation is like this: you want to **build some abstraction over the control flow of your code**. This is where the functional programming style comes in handy... In fact, in C++ the thing would be simple (well, not really trivial, but do-able in a type-safe and portable way, with some template magic strange functions with `bind` in their names).

We're talking about C not C++, no templates, no functors... so the matter is probably more complicated than that. But first things first- **what stops you from using the simple solution with if's**? Answering this question is a good start.

Comment: +1 for "rethink your design". I see way too many cases of people committing horrible hacks that invoke undefined behavior not for the sake of achieving any functional goal, only for the sake of trying to force C to meet some preconceived abstraction they have in their head that simply does not work or make sense in C.

Comment: if it was up to me, I'd never make such a horrible design, I didn't like it in the first place, it was imposed on me

Comment: +1 for "rethink your design."  The path you're going down doesn't end well, and future people will curse you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.  The preferred one is to pass your input via a `struct` that has an input type and various values defined for that type of input.  Then you just pass the `struct` to your function (by reference/pointer).

The second option is to format the arguments so that you can read them using `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end`.  To use this, you would need to know the type of the next arg, so you would need to have that passed as an input.  You also need to know in advance when the last arg is reached, so again, you'll need to pass that as an input.  This is the same way `printf` works, and why you need to pass the format string to `printf`.